# Look-back clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

Using SQL how might I write a query that grabs the first non null value of Field2 but looks back and outputs the '4' in Field1 and the '7' in field two?

Basically I am looking to take the first occurance that Field 2 is not null, slice off everything after that, and look back at the last non null value of Field1.

Example Below:

```
H_T | ID| Field1 | Field2  
1   | 1 | 1    | N         
2   | 1 | 4    | N  
3   | 1 | N    | 7   
4   | 1 | 2    | N
```

Please excuse the horrid formatting and please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: What defines the order? `H_T` column? Do you want it by `ID`?

Comment: This question looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827542/get-distinct-record-based-on-column-if-latest-value-is-null-take-old-value-else Depending on the database server you use, you could look at the `LEAD`, `LAG` or `NTH_VALUE` window functions; not sure if they will help for this though.

Comment: Vertica supports window functions including lead() and lag(): http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LAGAnalytic.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%20Reference%20Manual|SQL%20Functions|Analytic%20Functions|_____13